# Switching between two plots with groups in Plotly

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

I have a data frame with 2 columns, one that I want to use as a toggle (so display grp1 or grp2) and another where I want to split the data into different lines. I can't seem to figure out how to get it to work properly with plotly, I think there should be a simple straightforward way to do it but for the life of me I can't get it to stop mixing up the groups.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)
# example data my group 1 would be social, group 2 would be grp
df1 = data.frame(grp = "A", social = "Facebook",
            days = c("2020-01-01","2020-01-02","2020-01-03","2020-01-04"),
            yval = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4))
df2 = df1
df2$grp = "B"
df2$yval = df2$yval + 0.2
df3 = df1
df3$grp = "C"
df3$yval = df3$yval + 0.4
df = rbind(df1, df2, df3)
aux = df
aux$social = "Twitter"
aux$yval = aux$yval + 0.1
df = rbind(aux, df)
rm(aux, df1, df2, df3)
df$days = as.Date(df$days)
df$social_group = paste(df$social, df$grp)

ggplot(data = df, mapping = aes(x = days, y = yval, color = social)) + geom_point() + geom_line() + facet_wrap(facets = ~social)
```

[image: ggplot visualization aid]

So what I'm trying to do is to create a plotly that lets me switch between the ggplot facets, by toggling a Facebook or Twitter button.

This is what I currently got, which *starts* well, but as soon as I toggle the buttons the groups seem to mix, which shouldn't be happening when I consider I'm filtering on another column...

```
facebook_annotations <- list(
  data=df %>% filter(social=="Facebook"),
  x=~days, 
  y=~yval,
  color = ~grp,
  hovertemplate = paste('%{x}', '<br>Hover text: %{text}<br>'),
  text=~days
)

twitter_annotations <- list(
  data=df %>% filter(social=="Twitter"),
  x=~days, 
  y=~yval,
  color = ~grp,
  hovertemplate = paste('%{x}', '<br>Hover text: %{text}<br>'),
  text=~days
)

# updatemenus component
updatemenus <- list(
  list(
    active = 0,
    type = "buttons",
    buttons = list(
      list(
        label = "Facebook",
        method = "update",
        args = list(list(visible = c(TRUE, FALSE)),
                    list(title = "Facebook",
                      annotations = list(facebook_annotations, c())))),
      list(
        label = "Twitter",
        method = "update",
        args = list(list(visible = c(FALSE, TRUE)),
                    list(title = "Twitter",
                         annotations = list(c(), twitter_annotations)))))
  )
)

fig <- df %>% plot_ly(type="scatter", mode="lines") 

fig <- fig %>% add_lines( 
  data=df %>% filter(social=="Facebook"),
  x=~days, 
  y=~yval,
  color = ~grp,
  hovertemplate = paste('%{x}', '<br>Hover text: %{text}<br>'),
  text=~days
) 

fig <- fig %>% add_lines(
  data=df %>% filter(social=="Twitter"),
  x=~days, 
  y=~yval,
  color = ~grp,
  hovertemplate = paste('%{x}', '<br>Hover text: %{text}<br>'),
  text=~days,
  visible=FALSE
) 

fig <- fig %>% layout(title="Facebook",
                      xaxis=list(title=""),
                      yaxis = list(range = c(0, 1), title = "My Title"),
                      updatemenus=updatemenus)

fig
```

[image: Initial figure before interaction]

[image: When I click]
[image: When I click the other]

What am I missing? It's driving me crazy, I'm even considering just adding each group as an individual trace, but that's not really practical when my actual case study has 8 groups...